# Setting values of textboxes inside gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a gridview on my ASP.Net application form. My requirement is to change the values of 4 labels inside the gridview row on the `change` event of the `txtCTHOrHSN` textbox which is also inside the gridview.

I am using the following jQuery code to fetch the value of this textbox and another value which is coming from a label in the same row of the gridview, however the label values are not changing. Please help me out with this.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Data found..!" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin-bottom no-border-top" DataKeyNames="Id, tableName">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" Text="Approve" OnClick="btnApprove_Click" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CTH / HSN">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCTHOrHSN" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="tHSN" Text='<%# Eval("CTHOrHSN") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <input id="hdItemCode" type="hidden" runat="server" class="hidItemCode" value='<%#Eval("ItemCode") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Basic Duty (INR)">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalBasicDutyINR" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="tBasicDuty" Text='<%# Eval("TotalBasicDutyINR") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Basic Duty (As per HSN Master) (INR)">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblBasicDutyAsPerHSNMaster" runat="server" CssClass="l_BasicDuty" Text='<%# Eval("BasicDutyAsPerHSNMaster") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SWS (INR)">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSWSDutyAmt" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="tSWS" Text='<%# Eval("SWSDutyAmt") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SWS (As per HSN Master) (INR)">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSWSAsPerHSNMaster" runat="server" CssClass="l_SWS" Text='<%# Eval("SWSAsPerHSNMaster") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Health Cess (INR)">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHealthCess" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="tHealthCess" Text='<%# Eval("HealthCess") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Health Cess (As per HSN Master) (INR)">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblHealthCessAsPerHSNMaster" runat="server" CssClass="l_HealthCess" Text='<%# Eval("HealthCessAsPerHSNMaster") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IGST (INR)">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtIGST" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="tIGST" Text='<%# Eval("IGST") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IGST (As per HSN Master) (INR)">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblIGSTAsPerHSNMaster" runat="server" CssClass="l_IGST" Text='<%# Eval("IGSTAsPerHSNMaster") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Duty (INR)">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalDutyINR" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalDutyINR") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tHSN").change(function() {
    var HSNCode = $('.tHSN').val();
    var ItemCode = $(this).closest('tr').find('.hidItemCode').val()

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "frmDeviationApproval.aspx/GetDutyDetails",
      data: "{ HSNCode: '" + HSNCode + "', ItemCode: '" + ItemCode + "'}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      async: "true",
      cache: "false",
      success: function(response) {
        var FilteredData = [];
        FilteredData = JSON.parse(response.d);
        var data = FilteredData[0];

        $(this).closest('tr').find('.l_BasicDuty').text(data.BasicDuty.toString());
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.l_SWS').text(data.SWS.toString());
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.l_HealthCess').text(data.HealthCess.toString());
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.l_IGST').text(data.IGST.toString());
      },
      error: function() {
        showPopup('error', 'Error in loading data. Please refresh the page and try again.', '');
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: The code works fine when I do this: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.l_BasicDuty').text('Test');`. Maybe the problem is in the ajax call or the fetched data.

Comment: The ajax call is fetching the data correctly. The problem is coming while assigning the values to the labels

Comment: I just tried `$(this).closest('tr').find('.l_BasicDuty').text('Test');`. But it didn't work

Comment: Well, it's working here. Check the browser console for javascript errors.